# CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH appears to not be working to override location of Anaconda3 qt cmake

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, anaconda

Anaconda3 brings with it an distribution of Qt5 and the associated cmake files used to locate the packages.

CMake's `find_package (Qt5 COMPONENTS [components] REQUIRED)` is binding to the Anaconda3 distribution of Qt5.

I'm building an `x86` MSVC application and Anaconda3 has a `x64` build of Qt5, so I can't just let it be as is.

In an attempt to override this behavior I have added `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=[relative path to Qt5 dir containing /lib/cmake]` to the cmake call but when the `CMakeCache.txt` is rebuilt after being deleted it keeps getting the component directories bound to the Anaconda3 distribution, (e.g. `Qt5Core_DIR:PATH=C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/Library/lib/cmake/Qt5Core`)

Given the CMake documentation is more opaque than the average man page, I'm at a loss of what to do next. What am I missing?

Comment: The correct variable is called `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` without the trailing `S`.

Comment: Noted, that was a typo in my question, it's correct in my script.

Comment: Also, *relative* path unlikely works correctly with `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`, use absolute path instead.

Comment: Anaconda appears to actively dominate any Qt search patterns. My options were to strip it from PATH for my build script environment, or uninstall it.
I'd gotten the Qt libs building with some use of the absolute path, but a call to windeployqt would not recognize the correct Qt installation so long as anaconda remained in PATH.